# Side by side vertical histogram in R

Tags: r

Saw this graph in a article,
can anyone tell me how to plot something similar?

[image]

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/gjabel/demoproj/man/pyramid.html

Comment: http://timriffe.github.io/Pyramid/help/Pyramid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "Tornado" plot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_diagram

Here is a "hack" way to make the plot using negative numbers and `ggplot2::geom_bar()`

```
df <- data.frame(
  variable=c("A","B","A","B"),
  Level=c("X","X","Y","Y"),
  value=c(.2,.3,-.2,-.3)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(variable, value, fill=Level)) +
  geom_bar(position="identity", stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]